# Envio de formularios a un correo

Tags: php, email

hola quiero que al llenar el formulario que puse en mi pagina los correo me lleguen a mi correo personal este es el codigo de mi formulario esta en html

```
  <div class="grid_6 preffix_1">
    <h2>Envianos tu mensaje</h2>
          <form id="contact-form">
              <div class="contact-form-loader"></div>
              <fieldset>
                <label class="name" title="Nombre">
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre:" value="" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"  />
                  <span class="empty-message">*Ingresa tu nombre</span>
                  <span class="error-message">*Caracter no valido.</span>
                </label>

                <label class="email" title="E-mail">
                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" value="" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
                  <span class="empty-message">*Ingresa correctamente tu Email.</span>
                  <span class="error-message">*Caracter no valido.</span>
                </label>
                <label class="phone" title="Celular">
                  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Celular:" value="" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers" />
                  <span class="empty-message">*Ingresar numero celular</span>
                  <span class="error-message">*Caracter no valido.</span>
                </label>

                <label class="message" title="Mensaje">
                  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Mensaje:" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
                  <span class="empty-message">*Es necesario llenar este espacio</span>
                  <span class="error-message">*Mensaje muy corto.</span>
                </label>
                <div class="ta__right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn" title="Limpiar" data-type="reset">Limpiar</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn" title="Enviar"data-type="submit">Enviar</a>
                </div>
              </fieldset> 
              <div class="modal fade response-message">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">¡Listo!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      Tu mensaje se envio exitosamente.
                    </div>      
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>   
  </div>
```

***.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo_electronico= $_POST['email'];
$poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
$sexo=$_POST['GrupoOpciones1'];
$aficiones=$_POST['comentarios'];
$radio= $_POST['GrupoOpciones2'];
$opinion=$_POST['opinion'];
$header = 'From: ' . $mail . ", de la poblacion ".$poblacion."\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

$mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $nombre . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Su e-mail es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "sexo" . $_POST['GrupoOpciones1'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "aficiones " . $_POST['comentarios'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "que opinas de nuestra pagina" . $_POST['GrupoOpciones2'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .="danos tu opinion".$_POST['opinion'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

$para = 'AQUÍ PONES TU CORREO';
$asunto = 'AQUÍ LO QUE QUIERAS';

mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);

echo 'mensaje enviado correctamente';

?>
```

Comment: Seria genial que muestres lo que has investigado e intentado para resolver tu problema. SO no es un servicio de codificacion. :P

Comment: he buscdo y encontrado que se tiene que genrar un php pero eh intendo con 2 y no me queda

Comment: muestra el php que tienes ?

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado, nosotros valoramos los intentos, ademas que te podriamos indicar el motivo de que no funcionara. Asi aprenderas mas. :P

Comment: como añado el codigo de php aqui?

Comment: Tienes un error tipografico en la siguiente linea: `$para = 'AKI PONES TU CORREO;`, le falta una comilla simple, corrigelo por favor.

Comment: listo, ya con eso tiene que correr?

Comment: revisa la libreria phpMailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar la función mail de php debes configurar el smtp en el php.ini.
Dependiendo de donde vayas alojar tú sitio, puede que no tengas acceso a este archivo.

Puedes utilizar una librería para enviar el correo en lugar de la función mail, ya que será mas fácil realizar la configuración del SMTP. Como esta librería de a continuación:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;'; //el host del smtp que vas a utilizar
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';  // El usuario del smtp
$mail->Password = 'secret';            // La contraseña del usuario del smtp
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            
$mail->Port = 587; //El puerto que vas a utilizar para conectarte al smtp                                   

//Correos a los que se envia
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');

//Contenido
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

$mail->send();
```

Más informacion de la librería en el siguiente enlace:
[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Este tipo de respuesta ( un comentario tipo "usa la librería/herramienta X" y un enlace a la misma) no encaja bien con lo esperado en StackOverflow, extiende tu respuesta explicando cómo debería usarla y por qué es una buena solución al problema expuesto

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes saber es que desde el HTML "puro" no puedes enviar emails...

Puedes realizar como bien dicen usando un simple programa escrito en PHP que te reenvie los datos del formulario a tu email.
Lo primero que puedes escribir es un fichero (por ejemplo de nombre info.php) con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Leelo desde el navegador (y así vemos la version de PHP que tienes y si está funcionando)

A partir de ahí podemos ayudarte...
Incluso con 3 simples lineas de PHP, pero hay que saber si tienes PHP instalado correctamente y te funciona !!!

---

Si lo tienes todo correctamente funcionando, simplificando es lo siguiente:

formulario.html

```
...
<form id="email" name="email" method="post" action="email.php">
 <input id="uno" name="uno" type="...">
 <input id="dos" name="dos" type="...">
 ...
 <button type="submit">enviar email</button>
</form>
...
```

El "programa PHP" (email.php) es tan sencillo como el que te pusieron arriba... Simplificandolo:

```
<?php
 $destino = "tu-email@email.com";
 $asunto = "....."; // Lo puedes poner fijo o recibirlo desde el form
 $v1 = $_POST['uno'];
 $v2 = $_POST['dos'];
 ...
 $mensaje = " ..." . "\n" . $v1 . "\n" . $v2 . "\n";
 mail($destino, $asunto, $mensaje);
?>
```